# JFreechart main image (excluding YLabel) width differ among plots

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using JFreechart to draw some reports in pdf. I am not sure how to describe this in the best way so I leave the plots below. For the two plots in the report, the widths of the time axis are not the same, as pointed by the arrow. Any hints how I may adjust this?

[this is a snapshot](http://s7.postimg.org/jgbx9fd3v/illu.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`Axis.setFixedDimension()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#setFixedDimension-double-) ([source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#line.1070)).

Note that this method is used in [combined plots](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartCombinedXYPlotDemo1.htm), precisely to align the axes of various plots. If this is suitable in your case, using [`CombinedDomainXYPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CombinedDomainXYPlot.html) to plot your two charts would be the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks trashgod. But I would like to draw seperate plots, as they have separate titles and legends. Is there any other way around?

Comment: You can use `Axis.setFixedDimension()` on two separate plots. It is just more manual work than if you would use combined plots directly.